# Create-react-app not working even after uninstalling and reinstalling

Tags: reactjs, macos, npm, npx

I've been having difficulties getting create-react-app to work on my mac. I created a new project and simply tried "npx create-react-app my-app" and it told me that my version of create-react-app was outdated and to uninstall it with "npm uninstall -g create-react-app" but after doing that I literally get 1 file that was audited and its completed. Then when I go and try to install it again I keep getting the same error message. The furthest the install goes is installing the node_modules, package-lock.json, and package.json files then stops and lets me know that my create-react-app is outdated and to do the same command. Im in this never ending loop of uninstalling and reinstalling.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong here. I've even done these commands
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npx clear-npx-cache to clear your npx cache.
npx create-react-app your-app

and still it tells me that my create-react-app is outdated. [screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QTfk.png)

I'm relatively new to react development but I have definitely started react projects before with no issues.

Comment: no need to use @latest

Comment: `npx create-react-app youp-app-name` will works fine

Comment: As it says, just remove global version and install locally using npm install create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue happen as did another colleague of mine. For me, installing it locally with `npm install create-react-app`  worked and for him he had to uninstall and reinstall node